# R advanced optimization

Tags: r, optimization, reactive

I'm trying to take an excel sheet, where optimization is being done with excel solver, and bring it into R where the optimization will also be done. I am new to optimization in R and also unsure how to complete it (or if there is a shortcut) considering the complexity of the optimization equation.

Where the data is a time series of 50 years, and A is a single value sum for the time series, with all other variables having a value per year.

```
A = sum(B)    
B = 4 * 3 * C
C = D^0.05
.....
I = C * 3 + L
J = S * G
K = min(T, J) 
.....
S = some value
T = some value
```

Where the excel solver has code of: 
optimize for the maximum value of A
Where S > 0 and S < 100
and T > 0 and T < 1

The equations are so complex tracing back to the parameter I am trying to  optimize on that I am struggling to disentangle them, thus why I skipped between letters above. I have looked at the optim package as well as lpSolve some but am really unsure how to go about this. Any suggestions, guidance, help would be greatly appreciated! Right now my only thought is that I have to spend the time to disentangle all the equations, regardless of how long and ugly the equation will be and then try and figure out how to use one of the optimization packages. Thanks.

Comment: Or alternatively, is there a way to get the equation excel solver is using?

Comment: If you don't understand the model it will not be so easy to translate it into another software system.

Comment: In Excel press ctrl-[ to highlight referenced cells of a particular cell and press Enter to get to the next reference.